# The `redirect_uri` parameter does not match a valid url for the application

Tags: asana, asana-connect

So this is really weird: But When trying to connect with Asana I get: 
`` Error: invalid_request: The `redirect_uri` parameter does not match a valid url for the application. ``

I have literally copied and pasted the example from [here](https://github.com/Asana/node-asana/tree/master/examples/oauth/script)

[image: See all set up]

I've literally done everything I can do (Ive been researching all day but nothing works - about 6 hours) What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Ashley - When do you get this error message, when navigating the browser to the authorization page? Are you setting the `ASANA_CLIENT_ID` and `ASANA_CLIENT_SECRET` environment variables to the values that identify and authenticate your app? For what it's worth, I just re-tried this example from scratch and had no issue, so it is likely some kind of configuration problem.

Comment: @GregS Hi, Yes I managed to fix it with opening a new window and making the user paste the token shown in that window. Although I dont like this method at all (for what I developed it was fine) but I was expecting  there to be a redirect with the token, rather than make the user copy and paste the token. I am developing a HTML5 app (electron) So you can probably see why this method makes the app feel sloppy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the variant of the special redirect URI, `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto` (same as the other, just `:auto` appended to the end) which is intended for apps that drive a browser themselves and can programmatically read out the token and close the window.

But for both of the redirect URIs you are using, the **title** of the window should read `Success <query-string>` where that string is the query parameters that would get passed to the redirect. So for the authorization flow it will include `code=...`.

Your app, assuming it controls a browser window, should be able to navigate to the URL, wait for it to load, read out the title, then close the window, all without user intervention (except for the user actually doing the authorization in the browser window, of course).

Comment: Thank you, Any chance of this being in the ASANA api docs? I couldn't find anything like that when researching?